# SVG Drawing Function Is Messing Up

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-animate

So, I'm trying to do this animation where I can carousel through the content on this page in a slideshow/multi-step form kind of manner. That's working pretty good. However, I have this SVG drawing function that I want to call for each specific "slide", when the transfer function has happened. So transfer forward to section or backwards to section has happened, the specific SVG for that section is drawn.
But my svg function is messing up - maybe all of it is?
I don't know. I'm a newbie, so please be nice to me about my code - even if it's not great.
Also, I included a big chunk of code so thank you to whoever reads through this. Love you in advance :).

```js
    const multiStepForm = document.querySelector("[data-multi-step]");
    const formSteps = [...multiStepForm.querySelectorAll("[data-step]")];
    let currentStep = formSteps.findIndex(step => {
      return step.classList.contains('active')
    });
  
    if(currentStep < 0) {
      currentStep = 0;
      showCurrentStep();
    };
  
    multiStepForm.addEventListener('click', e => {
      let incrementor
      if (e.target.matches("[data-next]")) {
        incrementor = 1
      } else if (e.target.matches("[data-previous]")){
        incrementor = -1
      }
  
      if(incrementor == null) return
      if(e.target.matches("[data-next]")){
        currentStep += incrementor
        showCurrentStep()
      } else if (e.target.matches("[data-previous]")) {
        currentStep += incrementor
        showCurrentStep()
      }
      
    });
    
    formSteps.forEach(step => {
      step.addEventListener('animationend', e => {
        formSteps[currentStep].classList.remove('hide')
        e.target.classList.toggle('hide', !e.target.classList.contains('active'))
      })
    })
    function writeSignature(totalDur, paths){
      // get all SVG elements - lines and dots
      const linePaths = document.querySelectorAll(paths);
      
      // reset the animation
      linePaths.forEach((linePath) => {
        linePath.classList.remove('animated')
      })
    
      // escape if no element is found
      if(!linePaths.length){
        return false;
      };
      
      // set animation duration to default if not set
      const totalDuration = totalDur || 7;
        
      linePaths.forEach((linePath) => {
        const pathElem = linePath;
            
        // get current path length
        const pathLength = linePath.getTotalLength();
            
        // set animation duration and delay
        pathElem.style.animationDuration = `${totalDuration}s`;
    
        // set dash array and offset to path length - to hide the path
        linePath.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', pathLength);
        linePath.setAttribute('stroke-dashoffset', pathLength);
      });
      
      // set 'animated' class to body which will start the animation
      linePaths.forEach((linePath) => {
        linePath.classList.add('animated')
      });
      return true;
    };
    function showCurrentStep() {
      formSteps.forEach((step,index) => {
        step.classList.toggle('active', index === currentStep)
        if(step.classList.contains('systems')){
          writeSignature(2.5, '.system-path');
        } else if(step.classList.contains('socials')){
          writeSignature(2.5, '.social-path');
        } else if(step.classList.contains('web')){
          writeSignature(2.5, '.web-path');
        }
      });
    };
```

```css
.main-content {
  width: 75vw;
  height: 75vh;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.main-content-svc{
  background:#3244AB;
}

.steps-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.multi-step-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.step {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer; 
  animation: fade 250ms ease-in-out forwards;
}


.systems-info, .social-info, .web-info{
  width: 60%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  gap: 40px ;
  padding: 25px;
}

.social-info h2, .social-intro,
.systems-info h2, .systems-intro,
.web-info h2, .web-intro{
  text-align: center;
}

.social-paras, .systems-paras, .web-paras {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.social-info h2, .systems-info h2, .web-info h2 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 5;
}
.social-intro, .systems-intro, .web-intro {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 5;
}
.social-para1, .social-para3,
.systems-para1, .systems-para3,
.web-para1, .web-para3 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}
.social-para2, .social-para4,
.systems-para2, .systems-para4,
.web-para2, .web-para4 {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 5;
}

#system-svgs {
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -10%;
  top: 10%;
}
#web-svgs {
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 5%;
}

.twitter-lines {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10%;
  bottom: 15%;
}
.facebook-lines {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20%;
  top: 12%;
}
.pinterest-lines {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  top: 5%;
}

#services-pg path {
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.animated {
  animation-name: writeSVG;
}

.buttons {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 2%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

.buttons button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}

.step.active {
  animation: slide 250ms 250ms ease-in-out both;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

@keyframes writeSVG {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(200%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.75);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
  <main id="svc-container" class="main-content main-content-svc">
      <div class="steps-container">
        <ul data-multi-step class="multi-step-container">
        
          <li id="systems" class="active step systems" data-step>
            <div class="systems-info">
              <h2>Systems</h2>
              <p class="systems-intro">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe, quis. Officia nam dignissimos quae, provident architecto consequatur similique, maxime quos voluptate aspernatur iure qui dolore velit nihil excepturi sequi cumque. Asperiores inventore, provident libero.</p>
              <div class="systems-paras systems-para1">
                <h4>1)</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe, quis. Officia nam dignissimos quae, provident architecto consequatur similique, maxime quos voluptate.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="systems-paras systems-para2">
                <h4>2)</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe, quis. Officia nam dignissimos quae, provident architecto consequatur similique, maxime quos voluptate aspernatur.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="systems-paras systems-para3">
                <h4>3)</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe, quis. Officia nam dignissimos quae, provident architecto consequatur similique.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="systems-paras systems-para4">
                <h4>4)</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe, quis. Officia nam dignissimos quae, provident architecto consequatur similique.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="system-svgs">
              <svg
              class="gears"
              version="1.1"
              viewBox="10 30 40 65"
              height="500px"
              width="500px">
                <g>
                  <path
                  class="system-path"
                  d="m 13.284612,59.22312 c -3.769554,0.0069 -5.504936,2.172975 -5.822185,4.820917 -0.270219,2.530855 1.764121,5.724608 5.043422,5.748017 8.288379,0.261994 7.743937,-10.409386 0.778763,-10.568934 z m 0.112676,17.376856 -3.689262,-0.322894 0.35566,-3.648968 C 9.511117,72.492687 8.940024,72.335648 7.806573,71.522526 L 4.887021,73.848285 2.502685,71.16152 5.279688,68.949221 C 4.683138,68.134826 4.413308,67.451118 4.309992,66.834016 L 0.325907,66.958484 0.203642,63.450079 4.050129,63.32984 c -0.03987,-0.562853 0.146358,-1.261368 0.600855,-2.120843 l -3.166947,-2.110354 2.131431,-2.8713 3.115091,2.075859 c 0.83433,-0.956181 1.451323,-1.151682 2.095643,-1.442827 l -1.114617,-3.762509 3.567131,-0.948651 1.109063,3.743719 c 0.639522,-0.02774 0.890155,-0.196898 2.540998,0.143113 l 1.693704,-3.680101 3.39612,1.403109 -1.693669,3.680101 c 0.893449,0.59492 1.443027,1.189839 1.946424,1.784759 l 3.561731,-1.514035 1.516606,3.202754 -3.458795,1.470261 c 0.22664,0.730152 0.433222,1.465318 0.271919,2.292456 l 3.703698,0.947806 -0.96611,3.389011 -3.569731,-0.913651 c -0.332382,0.786544 -0.690051,1.573088 -1.700462,2.359632 l 2.207297,3.09999 -3.071288,1.963345 -2.190881,-3.076837 c -1.230003,0.498413 -2.097299,0.634118 -2.835485,0.640714 z"
                  style="fill:none;stroke:#4cf5e1;stroke-width:0.5;opacity:1;"/>
                  <path
                  class="system-path"
                  d="m 14.354871,39.21616 c -2.709478,-1.447135 -4.730714,-0.543226 -5.906005,1.256879 -1.099582,1.733252 -0.781496,4.835506 1.565052,6.115827 5.858287,3.383243 9.285683,-4.573592 4.340953,-7.372706 z M 8.218108,51.874629 5.68432,50.218954 7.245368,47.706922 C 6.897007,47.395744 6.543091,47.061718 6.020087,46.034763 L 3.091316,46.598454 2.340444,43.729393 5.126248,43.193156 c -0.136984,-0.821037 -0.08612,-1.42134 0.0605,-1.909138 l -2.90558,-1.44447 1.167551,-2.594098 2.805255,1.394544 c 0.172752,-0.42398 0.556427,-0.859337 1.190352,-1.308191 L 5.925197,34.579705 8.483205,33.316351 9.977438,36.02343 c 0.941282,-0.372739 1.454309,-0.276974 2.021181,-0.240118 l 0.54585,-3.160864 2.901063,0.685525 -0.543117,3.145083 c 0.469174,0.226236 0.709689,0.199988 1.773531,1.082795 l 2.533069,-2.019146 1.936765,2.326942 -2.53305,2.019166 c 0.428738,0.77609 0.610526,1.419702 0.759153,2.045525 l 3.099486,0.272993 -0.05688,2.909364 -3.009904,-0.265115 c -0.0985,0.617378 -0.213207,1.230669 -0.625,1.769007 l 2.320552,2.114901 -1.906416,2.088132 -2.236566,-2.038498 c -0.520128,0.442957 -1.058417,0.876176 -2.065445,1.05793 l 0.47588,3.100841 -2.908057,0.242134 -0.472377,-3.077709 C 10.925532,49.970285 10.254154,49.734696 9.721688,49.455103 Z"
                  style="fill:none;stroke:#4cf5e1;stroke-width:0.5;opacity:1;"/>
                  <path
                  class="system-path"
                  d="m 28.625511,48.835168 c -2.229634,-0.294553 -3.430783,0.847615 -3.832237,2.386691 -0.364191,1.473635 0.580861,3.52139 2.518148,3.794952 4.880085,0.81124 5.419984,-5.535723 1.314089,-6.181643 z m -1.336771,10.27385 -2.155528,-0.482945 0.505015,-2.127362 C 25.322409,56.37495 24.997382,56.236945 24.392798,55.666839 l -1.914281,1.142642 -1.192961,-1.775985 1.820822,-1.086908 c -0.286991,-0.528331 -0.391333,-0.953587 -0.402589,-1.326306 l -2.365999,-0.242042 0.211053,-2.082183 2.284289,0.233628 c 0.02191,-0.335646 0.188419,-0.733527 0.526596,-1.205243 l -1.702303,-1.497472 1.49229,-1.527327 1.674426,1.472987 c 0.570595,-0.498756 0.951237,-0.565376 1.355762,-0.68633 l -0.355249,-2.310886 2.186002,-0.27786 0.353481,2.299348 c 0.380419,0.0342 0.542286,-0.0458 1.491032,0.285806 l 1.298769,-2.039778 1.894943,1.097839 -1.298749,2.039776 c 0.480285,0.422199 0.757224,0.817161 1.006855,1.208465 l 2.228469,-0.612273 0.638167,2.012064 -2.164064,0.594569 c 0.07505,0.449269 0.137833,0.899911 -0.02434,1.375747 l 2.113596,0.853238 -0.845006,1.925453 -2.037133,-0.822454 c -0.260075,0.438303 -0.535101,0.874607 -1.19612,1.259208 l 1.054898,2.006066 -1.974738,0.916536 -1.047062,-1.991089 c -0.767602,0.197003 -1.291427,0.208474 -1.728479,0.153902 z"
                  style="fill:none;stroke:#4cf5e1;stroke-width:0.5;opacity:1;"/>
                </g>
              </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
              <button type="button" data-next>Socials &rightarrow;</button>
            </div>
          </li>
          
          <li id="socials" class="step socials" data-step>
            <div class="social-info">
              <h2>Socials</h2>
              <p class="social-intro">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe, quis. Officia nam dignissimos quae, provident architecto consequatur similique, maxime quos voluptate aspernatur iure qui dolore velit nihil excepturi sequi cumque. Asperiores inventore, provident libero.</p>
              <div class="social-paras social-para1">
                <h4>1)</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe, quis. Officia nam dignissimos quae, provident architecto consequatur similique, maxime quos voluptate.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="social-paras social-para2">
                <h4>2)</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe, quis. Officia nam dignissimos quae, provident architecto consequatur similique, maxime quos voluptate aspernatur.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="social-paras social-para3">
                <h4>3)</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe, quis. Officia nam dignissimos quae, provident architecto consequatur similique.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="social-paras social-para4">
                <h4>4)</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe, quis. Officia nam dignissimos quae, provident architecto consequatur similique.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="social-svgs">
              <svg
              class="twitter-lines"
              version="1.1"
              viewBox="850 -750 850 850"
              height="250px"
              width="250px">
                <g>
                  <path
                    class="social-path"
                    d="M 1371.638,73.267145 C 1282.6632,22.881521 1106.9129,2.561158 970.86717,92.585006 c 77.31223,-9.378131 150.07103,0.994385 212.10653,57.880064 -111.4902,15.3279 -124.9095,72.0454 -138.2829,97.77243 23.7585,-0.63766 47.5168,-1.70582 71.2752,1.66802 -117.79397,38.56527 -117.01177,140.09919 -117.01177,140.09919 20.65097,-7.19842 40.39617,-16.36068 64.68037,-15.67906 -74.62377,63.10602 -75.21977,129.29951 -50.7356,196.53897 67.6896,-77.57075 148.9319,-143.78545 300.052,-151.44828 -24.0681,68.11848 91.7053,264.05661 242.5268,131.98727 25.9132,-7.82476 55.0522,12.33458 84.7542,37.37698 -7.0544,-30.76945 -6.1736,-62.11256 -68.4795,-88.88787 23.0316,2.70904 34.8831,-9.73587 86.3971,31.57969 -4.5985,-20.69531 -9.83,-49.22123 -56.3749,-69.87587 C 1603.3326,234.22266 1448.2495,107.3751 1371.638,73.267145 Z"
                    style="fill:none;stroke:#4cf5e1;stroke-width:8;opacity:1;"
                    transform="scale(1,-1)"/>
                </g>
              </svg>
              <svg
              class="facebook-lines"
              version="1.1"
              viewBox="950 -400 350 350"
              height="250px"
              width="250px">
                <g>
                  <path
                    class="social-path"
                    d="m 1185.4417,352.252 c -44.0308,-2.93942 -101.1573,17.27671 -93.0549,-92.7576 h -39.5234 v -45.95715 h 39.5234 v -111.4893 l 45.0653,0.1032 1.0479,111.3861 h 43.6481 V 259.4944 H 1138.5 c -1.2058,61.05759 4.347,49.63388 46.9417,50.07997 V 352.252"
                    style="fill:none;stroke:#4cf5e1;stroke-width:3.5;opacity:1;"
                    transform="scale(1,-1)"/>
                </g>
              </svg>
              <svg
              class="pinterest-lines"
              version="1.1"
              viewBox="1000 -475 450 450"
              height="250px"
              width="250px">
                <g>
                  <path
                    class="social-path"
                    d="m 1163.8809,110.83362 c -8.5615,-4.76259 -9.0546,17.97745 -12.8107,29.59485 1.5189,40.39107 19.7671,73.33812 24.3142,116.2338 -26.2638,59.88131 14.5762,86.97703 43.8842,84.21015 34.0357,-15.71279 1.2869,-68.27225 -5.9303,-106.74525 -7.607,-27.66551 37.4846,-41.47442 59.3029,-26.68637 73.4249,50.7141 26.9472,170.56116 -34.9887,166.64129 -76.3165,3.81259 -86.9575,-55.15298 -93.1057,-77.09384 -0.5338,-43.63739 18.4588,-31.04584 16.6049,-69.38443 -20.558,-4.54562 -40.4012,39.87221 -36.7679,74.1287 15.8015,101.49563 89.5039,98.80371 95.4778,100.81501 145.8932,0.59738 173.0445,-185.86557 51.5935,-224.75821 -35.3925,-6.01894 -54.291,9.53415 -68.0339,23.0914 -6.4287,-43.5186 -25.9041,-82.88567 -39.5403,-90.0471 z"
                    style="fill:none;stroke:#4cf5e1;stroke-width:4;opacity:1;"
                    transform="scale(1,-1)"/>
                </g>
              </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
              <button type="button" data-previous>&leftarrow; Systems </button>
              <button type="button" data-next>Web &rightarrow;</button>
            </div>
          </li>
          
          <li id="web" class="step web" data-step>
            <div class="web-info">
              <h2>Web</h2>
              <p class="web-intro">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe, quis. Officia nam dignissimos quae, provident architecto consequatur similique, maxime quos voluptate aspernatur iure qui dolore velit nihil excepturi sequi cumque. Asperiores inventore, provident libero.</p>
              <div class="web-paras web-para1">
                <h4>1)</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe, quis. Officia nam dignissimos quae, provident architecto consequatur similique, maxime quos voluptate.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="web-paras web-para2">
                <h4>2)</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe, quis. Officia nam dignissimos quae, provident architecto consequatur similique, maxime quos voluptate aspernatur.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="web-paras web-para3">
                <h4>3)</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe, quis. Officia nam dignissimos quae, provident architecto consequatur similique.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="web-paras web-para4">
                <h4>4)</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe, quis. Officia nam dignissimos quae, provident architecto consequatur similique.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="web-svgs">
              <svg
              class="web-build"
              version="1.1"
              viewBox="-15 -25 175 175"
              height="500px"
              width="500px">
                <g>
                  <path
                  class="web-path"
                  d="M 60.647144,112.82787 C 65.305556,104.58148 45.282102,73.931698 35.075129,51.835166 l -8.46641,3.628462 c 8.757646,15.108739 29.083175,62.837452 34.038425,57.364242 z"
                  style="fill:none;stroke:#4cf5e1;stroke-width:1;opacity:1;"/>
                  <path
                  class="web-path"
                  d="M 25.053664,53.563005 16.068902,29.546045 C 0.56706111,31.526934 9.1250601,19.272702 0,0 11.54679,19.242498 26.096809,12.560767 19.697363,27.299854 L 33.692858,49.76176 Z"
                  style="fill:none;stroke:#4cf5e1;stroke-width:1;opacity:1;"/>
                  <path
                  class="web-path"
                  d="M 73.433152,29.546045 V 42.159269 L 62.720551,46.997217 73.77872,52.180734 73.605936,65.485093 44.405459,47.342785 Z"
                  style="fill:none;stroke:#4cf5e1;stroke-width:1;opacity:1;"/>
                  <path
                  class="web-path"
                  d="M 102.63363,8.1208427 112.65509,8.2936266 86.564728,84.664105 H 75.852127 Z"
                  style="fill:none;stroke:#4cf5e1;stroke-width:1;opacity:1;"/>
                  <path
                  class="web-path"
                  d="M 114.21015,29.546045 141.68279,46.65165 113.51901,65.657877 V 52.00795 l 11.23096,-5.529084 -10.88539,-5.529085 z"
                  style="fill:none;stroke:#4cf5e1;stroke-width:1;opacity:1;"/>
                </g>
              </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
              <button type="button" data-previous>&leftarrow; Socials</button>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </main>
```

Comment: I don't know if it's the only problem - but you need to use setAttributeNS (not setAttribute) when you're setting an attribute on an SVG element.

Comment: I will change that @MichaelMullany thank you. I have used it before like this however, just outside of the carousel function thingy, and it worked perfectly fine...